# Adjective for something that inspires or originally motivates something else

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I am preparing a slide show and would like to title one slide as follows:

*[technology1]'s **[adjective]** idea*

which should mean something like

*The idea behind [technology1]*

or

*The idea that originally inspired [technology1]*

What could I use for [adjective]?

Comment: Can you give us an example of an idea behind a technology?

Comment: Theoretical? The lightbulb's theoretical idea was XXX.

Comment: *Core* would be too simple?

Answer (score 2):

> [Technology1]'s **foundational** idea

**foundational** (adj.)

> Of or relating to the basis or groundwork on which something rests or
> is built; needing to be understood or established at the beginning:
>
> *We believe that fostering a strong local community is a foundational component of our inner-city scholarship program, guiding everything
> else we do.* [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/foundational)

> Of, relating to, or forming or serving as a base or foundation: FUNDAMENTAL
>
> *foundational principles/doctrines* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/foundational)

---

> **Inspired** by Jean Piaget's (1954) **foundational idea** of the 'sensorimotor stage' in cognitive development, embodied cognition
> assumes that – in the form of mental schemata – conceptual
> representations and categories are fundamentally shaped by, and
> derived from, out bodily experiences with the physical properties of
> the world... [R. H. Jones; *The Routledge Handbook of Language and
> Creativity*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Routledge_Handbook_of_Language_and_C/-jBEDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22foundational%20idea%22%20inspiration&pg=PT91&printsec=frontcover)

> These assessment items were administered to Secondary Cycle One
> students (grades seven and eight) in Francophone and Anglophone
> schools in Québec to elicit their alternative ideas about the
> **foundational technology concepts** included in the science and technology curriculum in Québec. [Andrea Burrows; *Computer Science
> and Engineering Education for Pre-collegiate Students and
> Teachers*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Computer_Science_and_Engineering_Educati/yLKcDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=:the%20foundational%20ideas%20of%20technology%22&pg=PA73&printsec=frontcover)

> The volume's contributors include representatives of over half a dozen
> different disciplines, and each provides a novel perspective on the
> **foundational idea** that gender and technology cocreate one another. [M. F. Fox et al.; *Women, Gender, and Technology*, p.207](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Women_Gender_and_Technology/nf1E3EFqoXAC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22foundational%20idea%22%20technology&pg=PA207&printsec=frontcover)

> A **foundational idea** for sustainability is that the environment
> itself imposes limits on the manner in which economic and social
> development can be effectively conducted:... [Brent Steel; *Science
> and Politics*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Science_and_Politics/0kl1AwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22foundational%20idea%22%20science&pg=PA500&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: I doubt that there’s a foundational idea behind technology.

Comment: @Xanne behind *a particular* technology (hence "[technology**1**]")